# PHP AJAX Comet with MySQL select record

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I would like to implement comet with records fetch from PHP

My PHP will do the following.. at a page call **getlog.php**

```
$sql = "select log_description,log_time from log ORDER by log_time DESC";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result == false)
{     die("unable to fetch records."); }

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $result_output[] = $row;
}

$counter = 1;
foreach($result_output as $row)
{
echo $counter . ".  " $row[log_description];
$counter++;
}
```

If there is new log, I would want to echo it out in **viewlog.php**

So it would appear like this in **viewlog.php**

```
1. Customer 1 logged in at 12:05.
```

maybe 5 minutes later

```
1. Customer 2 logged in at 12:10
2. Customer 1 logged in at 12:05
```

It maintain a maximum of like lets say 15 records.

The data is fetch from PHP, I read the way to do it is something call "comet" but I just want a simple database fetch which auto refresh e.g every 10 seconds to see if there is new record added to the database and append it to the div.

Is there a easy way to achieve this using AJAX and PHP and not using comet.

Thanks for all the help, greatly appreciate !

Did the following code changes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
   show_log(){
    var lnk = "fetchlog.php";
    $.ajax({url:lnk,success:function(result){
        $("#log_div").html(result);
    }});
}
   window.setInterval(function(){
  show_log();
}, 10000);
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="log_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Whats wrong with my code as it doesn't fetch from fetchlog.php

fetchlog.php echo something like this

```
1. Acct_1 logged to the system.
2. Acct_3  logged in to the system.
3. Acct_2  logged in to the system.
4. Assign permissions on Acct_1.
5. Delete record on table building with id 80
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3Exd/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use ajax for this and simply update a div in your html.
You need to have jquery linked in order to use the below code.

```
show_log(){
    var lnk = "link to the viewlog.php file";
    $.ajax({url:lnk,success:function(result){
        $("#log_div").html(result);
    }});
}
```

Run the show_log() function every x number of mins.
Have your viewlog.php show the last x number of records in the descending order of time.
You can update your sql to look like

```
$sql = "select log_description,log_time from log ORDER by log_time DESC LIMIT 5 ";
```

You can use the below inside your javascript to run the function every x number of seconds. In this every 10 seconds.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  show_log();
}, 10000);
```

the 10,000 is in miliseconds

----- Try the below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
http = getHTTPObject();

function getHTTPObject(){
  var xmlhttp;

  if(!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined'){
    try {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch(e){
      xmlhttp = false;
    }
  }
  return xmlhttp;
}
function   show_log(){
    var url = "viewlog.php";
  http.open("GET", url, true);
  http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
  http.send(null);
}
function handleHttpResponse(){
  if(http.readyState == 4){
    document.getElementById('log_div').innerHTML = http.responseText;
  }
}
   setInterval ( "show_log()", 5000 );
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="log_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do I set it to run at every 10 seconds

Comment: is there a way i can made some "blinking" or "flashing" when there is new record compare to the previous div content.

Comment: It certainly doable. But then our approach will be different. The original answer I suggested simply takes the last 5 logs and shows. Certainly it doesn't record the last result in order for comparison. You can either a) Store the last log id in a session and update your php to do some nice css effects like making the new entries in red or something. b). Use a seperate function to check if there are any new entries and do some css to your div.

Comment: You can store the last log id in a javascript variable, use ajax to get the last log id, if the id's match then do nothing. but if different then show a nice effect

Comment: Hi, i updated my question with the code but the log still does not appear

Comment: The first thing is to actually check if the page gets called. Can you check the javascript console in your browser and let us know?

Comment: Its works ! Anyway can you help me with adding this highlight effect to show data reload when its able to fetch new data     $('#log_div').effect("highlight", {color: 'blue'}, 3000);

Comment: Try adding the $('#log_div').effect("highlight", {color: 'blue'}, 3000); after document.getElementById('log_div').innerHTML = http.responseText;. Let me know how it goes. Or if you see any issues, what the issue is. ;). Glad to see that it worked

Comment: Did it but nothing happen :)

Comment: Why did the answer above decide to use Ajax obj instead of $.ajax, which dramatically reduces the number of lines of code, feels like an regression almost. Although, as it does work, nice answer =)